# How to do this in SQL (PostgreSQL Window Function?)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a situation in SQL (PostgreSQL specifically) that I'm struggling with. The schema/model that I'm working with is not under my control and not something I'm able to alter, so I am trying to figure out the best way to deal with the cards I've been dealt.

First, the schema, simplified for this question, but essentially it's invoice (Type = T) and transaction (Type <> T) lines combined into the same table. There can and will be n-number of tranaction lines per invoice and n-number of invoices per client.

| Id | Type | InvoiceNo | ClientId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | I | 100 | 1 |
| 99 | X | 0 | 1 |
| 98 | S | 0 | 1 |
| 97 | T | 0 | 1 |
| 96 | I | 99 | 1 |
| 95 | X | 0 | 1 |
| 94 | S | 0 | 1 |

What I ultimately would like to end up with is something like the below, with the Invoice (Type = I) records removed and the Transaction (Type <> T) records that fall after each Invoice record populated with it's corresponding InvoiceId value.

| Id | Type | InvoiceNo | ClientId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | X | 100 | 1 |
| 98 | S | 100 | 1 |
| 97 | T | 100 | 1 |
| 95 | X | 99 | 1 |
| 94 | S | 99 | 1 |

So far, the closest I've been able to get, which isn't very close, is using the below SQL:

```
select 
    t1.Id, 
    t1.Type, 
    t2.InvoiceNo, 
    t1.ClientId 
from table AS t1 
join (select 
          Id, 
          InvoiceNo,
          ClientId
      from table
      where type = 'I') as t2
on t1.ClientId = t2.ClientId
where t1.ClientId = t2.ClientId and t1.Id <= t2.Id and t1.Type <> 'I'
```

The result of that looks something like the below, which works fine for the first invoice per client and then creates extra transaction records for each invoice

| Id | Type | InvoiceNo | ClientId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | X | 100 | 1 |
| 98 | S | 100 | 1 |
| 97 | T | 100 | 1 |
| 95 | X | 100 | 1 |
| 95 | X | 99 | 1 |
| 94 | S | 100 | 1 |
| 94 | S | 99 | 1 |

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

** **Updated with more complex example** **

Source:

| Id | Type | InvoiceNo | ClientId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | I | 97 | 1 |
| 3 | S | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | X | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | S | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | I | 98 | 2 |
| 7 | S | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | X | 0 | 1 |
| 9 | I | 99 | 1 |
| 10 | T | 0 | 1 |
| 11 | S | 0 | 1 |
| 12 | X | 0 | 1 |
| 13 | I | 100 | 1 |

Playing with the answer below, I came up with:

```
select * from (select t.*,
   max(InvoiceNo) filter (where type = 'I') over (partition by clientid order by id DESC) as imputed_invoiceno 
from t) as x
where Type <> 'I';
```

Which gets me close:

| Id | Type | InvoiceNo | ClientId | imputed_invoiceno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | X | 0 | 1 | 100 |
| 11 | S | 0 | 1 | 100 |
| 10 | T | 0 | 1 | 100 |
| 8 | X | 0 | 1 | 99 |
| 7 | S | 0 | 1 | 99 |
| 5 | S | 0 | 1 | 99 |
| 1 | X | 0 | 1 | 99 |
| 4 | X | 0 | 2 | 98 |
| 3 | S | 0 | 2 | 98 |

Best case result:

| Id | Type | InvoiceNo | ClientId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | X | 100 | 1 |
| 11 | S | 100 | 1 |
| 10 | T | 100 | 1 |
| 8 | X | 99 | 1 |
| 7 | S | 99 | 1 |
| 5 | S | 99 | 1 |
| 1 | X | 97 | 1 |
| 4 | X | 98 | 2 |
| 3 | S | 98 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you can use a cumulative window function:

```
select t.*,
       min(invoiceno) filter (where type = 'I') over (order by id desc) as imputed_invoiceno
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks. That does seem to work for the simplified example, but I'm struggling translating that to my real life use case which is a bit more complex. I've updated my post with a more realistic example of the source and corresponding preferred result. Hope it's something simple that I'm just struggling to understand!

Comment: @ataber . . . This question is answered.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with data and explanation more similar to your actual problem.

Comment: OK, if you're interested in the new question it's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66211119/postgresql-window-function-usage-question-with-specific-example