# PostgreSQL, Window function usage question (with specific example)

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a situation in PostgreSQL that I'm struggling with. The schema/model that I'm working with is not under my control and not something I'm able to alter, so I am trying to figure out the best way to deal with the cards I've been dealt.

First, the schema, simplified for this question, but essentially it's invoice (Type = T) and transaction (Type <> T) lines combined into the same table. There can and will be n-number of tranaction lines per invoice and n-number of invoices per client that can be intermingled as seen below.

Given this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
Type VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
InvoiceNo VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
ClientId VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL);
```

and this data:

```
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('X', '0', '1');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('I', '97', '1');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('S', '0', '2');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('X', '0', '2');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('S', '0', '1');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('I', '98', '2');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('S', '0', '1');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('X', '0', '1');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('I', '99', '1');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('T', '0', '1');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('S', '0', '1');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('X', '0', '1');
insert into t (type, InvoiceNo, ClientId) values ('I', '100', '1');
```

which looks like:

| Id | Type | InvoiceNo | ClientId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | X | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | I | 97 | 1 |
| 3 | S | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | X | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | S | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | I | 98 | 2 |
| 7 | S | 0 | 1 |
| 8 | X | 0 | 1 |
| 9 | I | 99 | 1 |
| 10 | T | 0 | 1 |
| 11 | S | 0 | 1 |
| 12 | X | 0 | 1 |
| 13 | I | 100 | 1 |

the result I'm looking for:

| Id | Type | InvoiceNo | ClientId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | X | 100 | 1 |
| 11 | S | 100 | 1 |
| 10 | T | 100 | 1 |
| 8 | X | 99 | 1 |
| 7 | S | 99 | 1 |
| 5 | S | 99 | 1 |
| 1 | X | 97 | 1 |
| 4 | X | 98 | 2 |
| 3 | S | 98 | 2 |

Playing with an answer from a previous question, I came up with:

```
select * from (select t.*,
   max(InvoiceNo) filter (where type = 'I') over (partition by clientid order by id DESC) as imputed_invoiceno 
from t) as x
where Type <> 'I';
```

Which gets me close:

| Id | Type | InvoiceNo | ClientId | imputed_invoiceno |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | X | 0 | 1 | 100 |
| 11 | S | 0 | 1 | 100 |
| 10 | T | 0 | 1 | 100 |
| 8 | X | 0 | 1 | 99 |
| 7 | S | 0 | 1 | 99 |
| 5 | S | 0 | 1 | 99 |
| 1 | X | 0 | 1 | 99 |
| 4 | X | 0 | 2 | 98 |
| 3 | S | 0 | 2 | 98 |

The only issue here is that record with Id = 1 should have imputed_invoiceno = 97, but doesn't and I'm unclear as to why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something strange is going on with the string type.  You get the expected results with this query using numbers:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             min(InvoiceNo) filter (where type = 'I') over (partition by clientid order by id desc) as imputed_invoiceno 
      from t
     ) x
where Type <> 'I';
```

Note that I changed the `max()` to a `min()`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a6bdd871f1646de5d8127ae68ebca2a6) is a db<>fiddle.

The issue is that the ordering for strings is not what you expect.  It is not `0 < 97 < 98 < 99 < 100`.  It is `'0' < '100' < '97' < '98' < '99'`.  I think you worked around this using `max()`.